# What does libc_hidden_builtin_def (strspn) mean?

Tags: c, gnu, glibc

```
libc_hidden_builtin_def (strspn)
```

I found the code above in `glibc-2.18/string/strspn.c`.
Can someone explain what this mean. Is this important to rest of the code?
Here is the content of the file `strspn.c`:

```
#include <string.h>

#undef strspn

/* Return the length of the maximum initial segment
   of S which contains only characters in ACCEPT.  */
size_t strspn (s, accept) const char *s; const char *accept; {
  const char *p;
  const char *a;
  size_t count = 0;

  for (p = s; *p != '\0'; ++p) {
      for (a = accept; *a != '\0'; ++a) {
        if (*p == *a)
           break;
        if (*a == '\0')
           return count;
        else
          ++count;
     }
  }

  return count;
}
libc_hidden_builtin_def (strspn)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can someone explain what this mean.

It's a `#define`d macro, which expands to nothing when building (non-shared) libc.a, and to:

```
extern __typeof (strcspn) __EI_strcspn __asm__("" "strcspn");
extern __typeof (strcspn) __EI_strcspn __attribute__((alias ("" "__GI_strcspn")));
```

when compiling libc.so.6.

What this does is define a symbol alias `__GI_strcspn` that has the same value as `strcspn`, but is not exported out of libc.so.6 (i.e. it's an internal symbol).

> Is this important to rest of the code?

Yes: other code inside `libc.so.6` may call this symbol without possibility to interpose it in e.g. `LD_PRELOADED` library.